# ggplot: geom_errorbar: Error in "var"- se : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

How to handle error "Error in rate - se : non-numeric argument to binary operator"?

My code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=zone, y=rate, fill=race))+geom_bar(stat   ="identity",position="dodge")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=rate-se, ymax=rate+se))
```

My data:

```
race<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
zone<-c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3)
rate<-c(10.9,7.7,12.9,9.2,12.5,9.6,10.4,5.1)
se <-c(0.001,0.103,0.066,0.099,0.0060,0.062,0.096,0.001)
df <- data.frame(race, zone, rate,se)
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: That code works for me with that data. Are you getting that error with different data? Possibly there's missing values?

Comment: Spacedman, i still get this error. frustrating. i dunno what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've got character data masquerading as numbers...

With what looks like your data:

```
> zorace
  racecat zone      rate          se
1       1    0 10.886621 0.001159755
2       2    0  7.763123 0.103422900
3       1    1 12.926866 0.065986546
4       2    1  9.196214 0.098244182
5       1    2 12.487529 0.060695012
6       2    2  9.626924 0.062437645
7       1    3 10.378148 0.096269240
8       2    3  5.042412 0.001159755
```

I get no errors:

```
> ggplot(zorace, aes(x=zone, y=rate, fill=racecat))+geom_bar(stat ="identity",position="dodge")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=rate-se, ymax=rate+se))
```

But if I convert the `se` column to characters:

```
> zorace$se=as.character(zorace$se)
```

It looks *almost* the same:

```
> zorace
  racecat zone      rate          se
1       1    0 10.886621 0.001159755
2       2    0  7.763123   0.1034229
3       1    1 12.926866 0.065986546
4       2    1  9.196214 0.098244182
5       1    2 12.487529 0.060695012
6       2    2  9.626924 0.062437645
7       1    3 10.378148  0.09626924
8       2    3  5.042412 0.001159755
```

BUT:

```
> ggplot(zorace, aes(x=zone, y=rate, fill=racecat))+geom_bar(stat ="identity",position="dodge")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=rate-se, ymax=rate+se))
Error in rate - se : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>
```

What does `summary(zorace)` tell you about the columns? I suspect you've accidentally converted something to character, or its been read in as character from a file with non-numeric fields that have been filtered out since.

It's odd that your "number" columns align to the left - I suspect there's some spaces padding them out to a fixed length.

Convert back to numbers with:

```
 zorace$se = as.numeric(as.character(zorace$se))
```

Converting to character first protects you against if `se` is a factor variable, in which case it would get converted to numeric 1 to N.

Comment: Bravo. Converting se to numeric solved the problem. I manually inputted se that made it born character from get go, I guess. Thanks a lot.